# Vim Regex gives incorrect output

Tags: regex, vim, vi, backreference

I have a list of dates (YYYY-M or YYYY-MM) and want to prefix `0` before the first 9 months for consistency. Data format : Date in YYYY-M or YYYY-MM followed by a comma and a number.
Eg:

```
2012-1,789
2012-11,563
```

`2012-1,789` should be changed to `2012-01,789`. The entry `2012-11,563' should remain unchanged.

Correct output should be:

```
2012-01,789
2012-11,563
```

I tried following regular expression in Vim.

```
:%s/-\(\d\),/-0\0,/g
```

However, I get the following output:

```
2012-0-1,789
2012-11,563
```

Why am I getting an additional dash `-` between two digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capturing group number starts from `1`, not from `0`.

So the command should be:

```
:%s/-\(\d\),/-0\1,/g
```

Comment: What does group 0 stand for?

Comment: @Ajax, group 0 = the entire matched string.